# React app display blank page after compiling with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to understand what the problem is. Once compiled with npm run dev i have a blank page. I have also some warnings but i'm not sure if this would block the page of being loaded? Mostly because of size limit, i'm not too sure how to fix this either.

[image]

webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path:path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test:  /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
          },  
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader : 'file-loader'
          }
    ]
},
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
      "React": "react"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
    })
  ],
}
```

src/index.js

```
import App from "next/app";
import { ParallaxProvider } from 'react-scroll-parallax';
import './App.css';
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";
class MyApp extends App {
   render() {
const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
 return (
    <ParallaxProvider><Component {...pageProps} /></ParallaxProvider>
 )}};

export default MyApp;
```

src/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans|Lobster"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-227115773-1"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

src/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';
import Routes from './router';
import AppProvider from './AppProvider';

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppProvider>
      <>
        <Routes />
      </>
    </AppProvider>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "sitemap": "babel-node ./sitemap-generator.js"
  },
```

The console output is as per below:

webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.1.6:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv6): http://[fe80::7fed:f21:a401:a783]:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\projects\weblegion\public' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
assets by path *.jpg 5.22 MiB
  asset 6a6d933c9003e7697a89d05921c66b4a.jpg 1.47 MiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/hero2.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset 8efd6791fe97cb571ae6ac94807bd163.jpg 815 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/pricing.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset bda57d14e25bfb651b09b5884207aed5.jpg 682 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/default.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset 3900dc2ac8f4ae2cf613c363f6750c51.jpg 653 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/about.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset 55e30cd4aa76bb5f97de3159a46fb00a.jpg 599 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/portfolio.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset e8604d9abce0652694684e071dd8366d.jpg 577 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/services.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset 8e7c885ae7c3eefc86eacdebcd1eedea.jpg 308 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/blog.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset 2f96bd65339290142bcd5727517258c2.jpg 204 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/contact.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset 03483b10527e161284b1.jpg 80 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/about.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset 039c860eb8037dc8ba70.jpg 80 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/portfolio.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  asset 63072024648ba9654164.jpg 80 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/img/blog.jpg] (auxiliary name: main)
  + 5 assets
asset main.js 828 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 933 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 27.6 KiB 14 modules
javascript modules 667 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 321 KiB 42 modules
  modules by path ./src/ 345 KiB
    ./src/index.js 4.29 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.css 2.24 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/App.css 339 KiB [built] [code generated]
asset modules 3.78 KiB (javascript) 640 bytes (asset)
  modules by path ./ 336 bytes (javascript) 640 bytes (asset)
    ./src/img/services.jpg 42 bytes (javascript) 80 bytes (asset) [built] [code generated]
    + 7 modules
  modules by mime type image/svg+xml 984 bytes
    data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0i.. 315 bytes [built] [code generated]
    + 2 modules
  data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAALAIAAAwAw.. 2.49 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.75.0 compiled successfully in 2200 ms
```

i'm expecting the content of index.js in the pages folder to be shown.

[image]

Comment: From what I can understand, a page was opened after you ran the command. And the page was blank. I think there's error in the run time, can you check the console?
If the error was in build time, webpack should have thrown some errors, instead of warnings

Comment: I have added more details in my post, ther eis no errors shown. It should just display what's in src/pages/index.js thanks

Comment: Can you upload contents of src/App.js and src/index.js?

Comment: done thanks hungdoansy

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `webpack.config.js`

```
devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
```